# How can I extract nouns excluding their articles and possessive cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

## Background

I would like to know how to separate nouns and their decorations, such as articles and possessive cases.

Example

```
#sentence
The man with the star regarded her with his expressionless eyes.


# what to extract 
man
star
eyes
```

## Problem

As the below image created using disPlacy tool, "The man, the star, and his expressionless eyes" are united as **NOUN**.

the visualizar of part of speech and dependencies

https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy

[image: the result of the sample sentence]

## What I tried

I've run the sample code introduced on [the spaCy page](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features).

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("The man with the star regarded her with his calm, expressionless eyes.")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.dep_, token.head.text, token.head.pos_,
            [child for child in token.children])
```

Using the below result or other ways, how can I extract nouns themselves excluding their articles and possessive case?

```sh
$ python sample.py
The det man NOUN []
man nsubj regarded VERB [The, with]
with prep man NOUN [star]
the det star NOUN []
star pobj with ADP [the]
regarded ROOT regarded VERB [man, her, with, .]
her dobj regarded VERB []
with prep regarded VERB [eyes]
his poss eyes NOUN []
calm amod eyes NOUN [,]
, punct calm ADJ []
expressionless amod eyes NOUN []
eyes pobj with ADP [his, calm, expressionless]
. punct regarded VERB []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to achieve the desired output you provide in your initial example:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

text = "The man with the star regarded her with his expressionless eyes."

for word in nlp(text):
  if word.pos_ == 'NOUN':
    print(word.text)
```

**Output:**

```
man
star
eyes
```

You could also consider using the [**nltk**](https://www.nltk.org/) package instead, since it may be faster, for this use case:

```
import nltk

text = "The man with the star regarded her with his expressionless eyes."

for word, pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(text)):
  if pos[0] == 'N':
    print(word)
```

**Output:**

```
man
star
eyes
```